# Copy file from local filesystem and process into db of another server

Tags: php, curl

Preface:
I have images being generated every few hours from a script. These images get saved to the local filesystem of a pi. My goal is to have a webpage display the latest image. I don't want the webserver running on the pi.

What I've tried:
I created a php upload handler from an HTML form. This takes an image from the form, and places it on the webserver filesystem and inserts an ID, filename, date, and path into a database. My idea was to post each image using curl from the pi to the webserver and have it upload and inserted into the DB, and then deleted from the Pi's filesystem right after. For whatever reason I can't get the curl to post to the HTML form.

I know this is pretty jank. I don't want to scp the images to the webserver and have a cron job running every minute to process any new files because I want it to be real time, and also don't want php processes just hanging out every minute.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have idea of RSYNC command?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar - good thought. Although this is going to my dev webserver, doing it this way allows me to not expose any extra daemons listening to the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone who looked!

I figured this out using curl - something was wrong in my upload.php
Here's the curl syntax: `curl -i -F "file=@/home/pi/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx.png" http://xxxxxxx.com/upload.php`

And here's the working upload.php

```html
<?php
include 'dbConfig.php';
$statusMsg = '';
$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
 $insert = $db->query("INSERT into images (file_name, uploaded_on) VALUES ('".$fileName."', NOW())");
 if($insert){
                $statusMsg = "The file ".$fileName. " has been uploaded successfully.";
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "File upload failed, please try again.";
            }
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
echo $statusMsg;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way might be:

1. Convert image to Base64 when generated. `$data = file_get_contents($path); $save_to_text_field = base64_encode($data);`
2. Save in database as longtext / blob (what are your options for text storage in the DB?)
3. show on webpage as data URI
   `<img src="data:image/png;base64,`[field]`>`

Comment: Interesting - I want to try and store the file on the web servers file system though so that the database isn't so large.

Comment: Just a thought... must the files be stored on the web server, or can you push the uploads to an S3 bucket (or similar) and do it CDN style??

Comment: I could push them out to anywhere really I guess, although I have a couple of dedicated servers so it wouldn't be worth it. I also would have to expose sql in order to make a connection to the database. I ended up figuring out the issue with what I was doing with curl, and it works fine now.

Comment: The goal here is for the user to go to a web page, and see last few hundred photos that were grabbed off some satellites. Like I said, this is kinda jank, but it appears to be working!